# Copy File in local Network

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is a web application 
I have 2 pc's: A: 192.168.1.200 and B: 192.168.1.201, I want copy from A to B, this code  working is single pc, but it's not working in network.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string sourcePath = @"D:\Source\";

    string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(sourcePath, "*.txt");
    foreach (string a in filePaths)
    {
        CopyFiles(a, a.Replace("D:\\Source\\", "D:\\Source1\\New\\"));
       //CopyFiles(a, a.Replace("D:\\Source\\", "192.168.1.201\\Source1\\New\\"));
    }

}

private  bool CopyFiles(string Source, string Destn)
{
    try
    {
        if (File.Exists(Source) == true)
        {           
            File.Copy(Source, Destn);
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("Source path . does not exist");
            return false; 
        }
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException  exFile)
    {
        Response.Write("File Not Found " + exFile.Message);
        return false;
    }
    catch (DirectoryNotFoundException exDir)
    {
        Response.Write("Directory Not Found " + exDir.Message);
        return false;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write(ex.Message);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to paste these files on the other computers Desktop, I will be using the IPv4 address and giving path after that like: C:\\Users\\ASUS\\Desktop\\? https://stackoverflow.com/a/10883763/9087709

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
CopyFiles(a, a.Replace("D:\\Source\\", "\\192.168.1.201\\Source1\\New\\"));
```

You also need to make sure that the Source1 folder is shared on B, and that you have write access to it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you create the Windows share "Source1" on the receiver machine?
If you did, I would try to mount it on your sender machine and change the code to:

```
CopyFiles(a, a.Replace("D:\\Source\\", "\\\\192.168.1.201\\Source1\\New\\"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to be allowed to write on the target machine. A work round can be used here, you can make a virtual drive pointing to a network place e.g Z:. Now you can use local notation. But before anything, get sure about permissions on the remote pc.

Comment: i m getting  error ... System.Security.SecurityException: The name provided is not a properly formed account name.

Comment: Do you use any Network Credential !? It seems you can not login on the remote machine.

Comment: AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetPrincipalPolicy(PrincipalPolicy.WindowsPrincipal);

        WindowsIdentity identity = new WindowsIdentity("192.168.1.201\\abc","12344");

        WindowsImpersonationContext context = identity.Impersonate();

Comment: Why you have entered "192.168.1.201\\abc" as the username ?! This is a Windows Identity, a pair of Username and Password. You should provide your username here. Be careful if you are in a domain, you should provide the username as this format : domain\username or username@domain

Comment: getting same error ** The name provided is not a properly formed account name**

Comment: Can you access the target machine using your explorer with this username ?!